# Android: Ensuring only one list item in a listview is expanded

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

So I currently have a `ListView` that has many list items. Each list item for example has two views, `View1` and `View2`, inside of it and has a long press listener. By default, `View2` is hidden until a long press is detected on the list item. The catch is that I would like only one list item to be showing both `View1` and `View2` at the same time. The rest of the list items should only be showing `View1`. How would I implement this?

I was thinking of keeping track of the id of ListItem that should be showing both views in the `ListFragment` and inside the `getView` method of the adapter, I would check whether the item I'm loading should show `View2`. Is this a good way to do it? In addition, once the long press is detected, should I be grabbing all visible cells and update the visibility of `View2` for each one?

Is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities come to my mind:

1) Have a variable 'currentItem' in your class. On longClick you refresh your listview (using notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter, for example), forcing it to redraw the items currently on screen, and have all items hidden except for 'currentItem'

2) Have a variable 'lastSelectedItem' in your class. On longClick you do something like this (in pseudocode)

```
currentSelection = // ... item returned from onLongClick
item(lastSelectedItem).hideView();
item(currentSelection).showView();
lastSelectedItem = currentSelection;
```

Comment: The only question I have regarding this is that getting the view of that item might not be the one that originally that item's considering that lists recycle their views. For your first solution, what do you mean by refreshing the view?

Comment: I edited answer. Also, you're right about the second approach might be trickier due to the recycling mechanism, but it could still work. If the previously selected item is **recycled or not**, you hide the view anyway.

Comment: That works right when the long press happens. However, when I start scrolling and views get recycled, where would I be storing the visibility of View2?

It feels like it's almost easier to keep track of an item ID of the long pressed item, and just comparing it everytime in getView. Then whenever another item is longpressed, I just notifydatasetchanged. I'll be giving this a try